# Seach data by multiple text box or one by one in gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 text boxes on an asp page and one search button. Users can search by entering text in any of the search boxes. I am using gridview with item temblate and bind with dataset. please tell me how to serach data by textbox. for ex: user can search by entering data in all 2 text boxes or 3 text boxes. please provide me any code or suggession for asp.net c#

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where ([ITEM NO#] like '%' + @search + '%' [Company Name] like '%' + @search1 + '%')";
   SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, con);

   xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;
   xp.Parameters.Add("@search1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RefNo.Text;

   con.Open();
   xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

   da.SelectCommand = xp;
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds, "ITEM No#");
   Search.DataSource = ds;
   Search.DataBind();
   con.Close();        
}
```

Comment: I have 2 text boxes on an asp page and one search button. Users can search by entering text in any of the search boxes. I am using gridview with item temblate and bind with dataset. please tell me how to serach data by textbox. for ex: user can search by entering data in all 2 text boxes or 3 text boxes. please provide me any code or suggession for asp.net c#.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Remove 3rd and 4th line and chage the query as below.

TextBox1.text is the Id 1st search textbox and
TextBox2.text is the Id of 2nd search textbox

```
string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where ([ITEM NO#] like '%" + TextBox1.Text == string.Empty ? null : TextBox1.Text + "%' OR [Company Name] like '%" + TextBox2.Text==string.Empty?null:TextBox2.Text + "%')";
```

Comment: It complains about "Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '%'."

Comment: string str = "Select [ITEM No#], [Company Name], [Discipline Required], [Service Description], Institution, [Award Date] from PSP_Report where ([ITEM NO#] like '%" + RefNo.Text == string.Empty ? null : RefNo.Text + "%' OR [Company Name] like '%" + CompanyName.Text == string.Empty ? null : CompanyName.Text + "%')";

Comment: Why u put Same Textbox Id for two textbox??

Comment: What was I supposed to put for textbooks? I think it's the same as TextBox1.Text